# Accessing android SD card

Tags: android, cordova, file-io

I'm trying to save my current webview in the android's cache (I have been told mnt/sdcard) however whether using the file explorer or trying to write to it in the code I recieve this error on my avd emluator:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/imageFolder/page.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

I also tried to make the directory first, but the mkdir() function returns false.
 I have the permission line in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here's my code:

```
public class screenCap extends DroidGap {

 private WebView myAppView;
    private DroidGap myGap;


 public screenCap(DroidGap gap, WebView view)
    {
     myAppView = view;
        myGap = gap;
    }   

//Captures the current webview and saves it as a jpeg so it can be loaded into
//the page flip html plugin
public void captureScreen(){

    myAppView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500,  Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
    myAppView.draw(canvas);

    //Create a directory to hold the temporary image
    File f =    new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/imageFolder/"+ "page.jpg");

    if (!f.getParentFile().exists());
    {
        f.getParentFile().mkdir();
        Log.d("DIRECTORY MADE!","!!!");
    }

    try {
        myAppView.getDrawingCache().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(f));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error--------->", e.toString());
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: Was `f.getParentFile().exists()` successful?

Answer (score 1):

This might be because your AVD may not have a SD card while you created it.

Select your `Virtual Device -> Edit -> Check SD Card field`.

If this is empty, enter a size there. Then re-run your application.

Comment: f.getParentFile().exists() returns false (which i believe is expected on the first run) and so does f.getParentFile().mkdir(); I do have the sd card set up by the avd manager with 2gb. I haven't tried saving it to one of my pc folders though, which is an option.

edit: After checking the state of the external memory with getExternalStorageState(), it says it is "removed". Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

f.getParentFile().exists() returns false (which i believe is expected on the first run) and so does f.getParentFile().mkdir(); I do have the sd card set up by the avd manager with 2gb. I haven't tried saving it to one of my pc folders though, which is an option.